# how to use the IDataContractSurrogate for sending System.Net.Mail.MailMessage in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-3.0

Can someone guide me towards implementing the IDataContractSurrogate for the MailMessage class in .Net Framework?

I'm currently trying to pass the MailMessage class as an object and it doesn't work...it throws the following exception...

> Type 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress'
>   cannot be serialized. Consider marking
>   it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute. See the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework documentation
>   for other supported types.

I would appreciate any help...

Thanks so much!!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate.aspx

Comment: I've seen that but I still can't figure out how to use the same concept for this object. In that example,they have control over the person class....over here I don't.. so,whats the solution?