# WCF How to make DataContract for an external class

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to use an already existing class from an other solution in my wcf service. So I have to add DataContract to it.

What is the best way of achieving this? 
I heard DataContract Surrogate would be a way but I don't really get how I have to use it.

**existing class**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public long Size{get; set;}
    public DateTime Birthdate{get; set;}

    public Person(string name, long size, DateTime birthdate)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Size = size;
        this.Birthdate = birthdate;
    }
}
```

That is how the external class looks like. Could someone show me an example how I have to put it in my wcf service.

**EDIT**

I have a windows service in which I have this class Person. My method in the windows service returns a list of Persons so `List<Person>`. Now I am trying to pass this list to my wcf service. Therefore I need to add DataContract to that class. Do I have to write a new class in the wcf service or can I hand over my class form the windows service.

Comment: If you can alter `Person`, then just add `[DataContract]`. A DataContract surrogate is only required if you cannot alter the class.

Comment: this class is from an other solution. How would it look like if I integrate it into my wcf service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember] public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public long Size { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, long size, DateTime birthdate)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Size = size;
        this.Birthdate = birthdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is it mentioned that the class is from an other solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You will have alter the class IN the other solution to add the WCF attributes. If you cannot do this then you need to create a surrogate as I said originally.

Comment: Ok I think I didn't explain well what I am doing. I am passing a List<Object> from my windows service to my wcf service. Now I need to give Object DataContract. Object is defined in the windows service. Do you get what I am trying?

Comment: So add the WCF attributes to Object in the windows service.

Comment: I would disagree strongly that the OP should solve this problem by somehow marking the Person type with attributes from System.ServiceModel - there is no information about where this type comes from, how often it changes, etc. It would be far better to define a separate data contract representing the Person type.

Comment: @Tom I probably agree with you Tom but until the OP can define their exact issue it is difficult to advise fully.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Perhaps "strongly disagree" is the wrong word. As always exceptions abound and yes it's very possible that the solution would be to do as you suggest. But in this case I doubt it as the type has been supplied in an external assembly, which leads me to think that the Person type is used elsewhere too.

Comment: And how exactly would that look like ?

Answer (score 2):

I have just voted [for **Tom Redfern** solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607684/wcf-how-to-make-datacontract-for-an-external-class/34611719#34611719), but to make the answer complete I would add more links, to allow author to decide, if he really wants to use surrogates or not. In very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297775/how-to-use-the-idatacontractsurrogate-for-sending-system-net-mail-mailmessage-in) very similar to Toms' suggestion was voted. You may go through the links in the comments and answers.

You can checkout yourself [what surrogates are and how to use them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx). Technically yes, you can use it for simulating and proxying of existing classes from 3rd party assemblies (**[here is very detailed example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/09/13/wcf-extensibility-serialization-surrogates/)**).

Why it can be the case for the question author? I think only if the real case is not a Person class from the question, but something really more complex.

> Surrogates have been around for a while, even before WCF, and their idea is simple: replacing one type A which is part of an object graph to be serialized with another type B (the “surrogate”). The main reasons why we’d want to do that are either because the type A isn’t serializable at all, or because it doesn’t have a serialization format which we want, so we use a surrogate to change it. The first case is straightforward – sometimes you have a type from a 3rd party or a legacy library which cannot be modified to accommodate serialization, but it’s part of the object graph which you want to exchange between client and server. One possible solution is to replicate the graph in Data Transfer Objects (DTO) which only contain the data which needs to be serialized. Sometimes, however, this may not be the best approach (too many types, high cost to convert between DTOs and objects with business logic, etc.), so a surrogate can be an way out. The second case (wanting to change the serialization format) doesn’t happen very often, but there are some scenarios where users want to change the way a type is serialized.

Comment: + 1 Thanks for providing that answer - to be honest with you I was not aware of the surrogate functionality and am frankly surprised they have been part of WCF since 3.0. I am guessing they have not been readily adopted in many solutions, though from the link I can concur that this would also satisfy the OPs requirement, albeit at the cost of increased complexity.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is the Person type defined in an assembly? Or it is bundled into an exe? If the latter, then although you can add a binary reference to the exe, it is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835635/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-reference-an-exe-file-in-c-sharp-project).

If it's defined in an assembly you *can* just use the Person type as a data contract type in your WCF service. You just create a binary reference to the assembly, this type will be serialized across the service boundary by the DataContractSerializer.

As MS says here:

> By default, the DataContractSerializer infers the data contract and
>   serializes all publicly visible types. All public read/write
>   properties and fields of the type are serialized

However, whether you *should* do this is another question.

It would be much easier to define a Person type inside the WCF project, expose that type (or a `List<>` of that type, as per your comments), and then have the client map their Person type to the Person type defined on the service when calling the service.

This is really the only option open to you if the type is wrapped up in a exe. Even if it's in a dll, you should still do this because it decouples the service from the consumer. Dependency direction should be consumer -> service not service -> consumer.

If you want to avoid writing mapping code, there are many [object mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286294/object-to-object-mapper) available.